# How to set the ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH directive?

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework

I'm installing Zend framework 1.11.11, and I want to set up a project by using Zend_Tool component. Since the `library` directory must be placed in `include_path` of php.ini file,or by using the `ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH` command.So how to use it to identify my `library`?

It's not working so:
`ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\library zf --setup`

Answer (score 0):

This style of setting an environment variable does not work in the windows cmd.exe-"shell". You have to do it first with the `set` command, then you can use the `zf` command:

```
set ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\library

rem from now on you can use zf without the "set" command
rem but you have to use set again if you open a new cmd.exe-instance.

zf --setup
zf create project ...

rem other zf commands
```

If you want to persist the `ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH` you have to set it in the windows system properties (Win-Button + Pause/Break) there you have to search for environment variables (on my Vista it's on Extended Settings -> Extended -> Environment variables - I don't know the exact names because my vista is in German). There you can add the variable. After that you have to start a new cmd.exe because the change is not applied to running processes (if you start the cmd.exe via explorer, you have to close all explorer-windows first).